# What is Dsolr.clustering.enabled for in Solr?

Tags: solr

I wanna to run a Solr Cluster! I added zookeeper ensemble configuration in `solr/bin/solr.in.sh`! But there is an option which is disabled by default and I don't know what is its relation to cloud mode and what is doing exactly if enabled!

```
#SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.clustering.enabled=true"
```

Comment: Results clustering was removed in Version 8 of Solr. You can still get it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706785/796025

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not related to running Solr in cloud mode (as a "cluster").

It [enables or disables the Clustering component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/result-clustering.html) - i.e. clustering of result sets.

> The clustering (or cluster analysis) plugin attempts to automatically discover groups of related search hits (documents) and assign human-readable labels to these groups.
>
> By default in Solr, the clustering algorithm is applied to the search result of each single query -— this is called an on-line clustering. While Solr contains an extension for full-index clustering (off-line clustering) this section will focus on discussing on-line clustering only.