# How to do Index clustering in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, cluster-analysis

As per the solr documentation, clustering supports online clustering and offline clustering (also known as Full Index clustering).
But the document has details about Online clustering only. (https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_7/result-clustering.html)

Can someone guide me on how to use index clustering?

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65532751/off-line-clustering-using-solr

Comment: We wanted to go for Index-based clustering rather than search clustering

Comment: @MatsLindh,

In that post, there is no much update on how to use index based clustering in Solr itself. It has been mentioned that the parameter is effectively dead. So, does it not work anymore?

I tried to look in Solr documentation but was not able to find any helpful information about that

Comment: @MKumar From the linked post: _there is no Solr plugin that can cluster the whole collection_. So it doesn't seem supported in its current form.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706785/796025